# Xamarin debug corrupted on newly created project causes terminating read: Bad file descriptor

Tags: debugging, xamarin, crash

This is a really weird problem. I was trying to create a sample project for a Xamarin problem I have. I created a 'blank' Xamarin project for Android, iOS and UWP and changed nothing. I ran it in Debugging mode and crash. The Debug output is

```
terminating
read: Bad file descriptor
read: Bad file descriptor
read: Bad file descriptor
read: Bad file descriptor
read: Bad file descriptor
read: Bad file descriptor
....
read: Bad file descriptor
read: Bad file descriptor
read: Bad file descriptor
Couldn't connect to logcat, GetProcessId returned: 0
Couldn't connect debugger. You can see more details in Xamarin Diagnostic output and the full exception on logs.
```

The diagnostics window says the following:

```
[D:]:                     $(MonoAndroidToolsDirectory) path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android` is valid
[D:]:                     $(MonoAndroidBinDirectory) path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android` is valid
[D:]:                     mscorlib.dll path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0` is valid
[D:]:                     GetSdkPath `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Version.txt` exists=False 
[D:]:                     GetSdkPath `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Version` exists=False 
[D:]:                     GetSdkPath `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Version.txt` exists=False 
[D:]:                     GetSdkPath `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Version` exists=False 
[D:]:                     GetSdkPath `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Version.txt` exists=False 
[D:]:                     GetSdkPath `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Version` exists=True 
[D:]:                     FindVersionFile: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Version, result=True
[I:]:                     Found Xamarin.Android 10.1.3.7
[I:sdk]:                  Runtime path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android
[I:sdk]:                  Framework path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0
[D:]:                     ValidateAndroidSdkLocation: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk`, result=True
[D:]:                     ValidateAndroidNdkLocation: ``, result=False
[I:]:                     Looking for Android NDK...
[I:]:                     Looking for Android SDK...
[D:]:                     ValidateAndroidSdkLocation: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk`, result=True
[D:]:                     ValidateAndroidNdkLocation: `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r13b`, result=True
[D:]:                     ValidateJavaSdkLocation: `C:\Program Files\Android\Jdk\microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25`, result=True
[I:]:                     Tracking android devices started
[D:]:                     TrackDeviceTask got: 22X7N19322000015 device
[I:]:                     Got new device list from adb with 1 devices
[D:]:                     Tracking avd started
[D:]:                     avd watcher *.ini path: 'C:\Users\Paul\.android\avd'
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 getprop
[D:]:                     avd watcher: got device list from avd with 1 devices
[I:]:                     Looking for Android SDK...
[D:]:                     ValidateAndroidSdkLocation: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk`, result=True
[W:]:                     AutoSdk cannot resolve dependencies: platform-tools@28.0.0
[D:]:                     ValidateAndroidSdkLocation: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk`, result=True
[D:]:                     ValidateAndroidNdkLocation: `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r13b`, result=True
[D:]:                     ValidateJavaSdkLocation: `C:\Program Files\Android\Jdk\microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25`, result=True
[D:]:                     $(MonoAndroidToolsDirectory) path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android` is valid
[D:]:                     $(MonoAndroidBinDirectory) path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\` is valid
[D:]:                     mscorlib.dll path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0` is valid
[D:]:                     GetSdkPath `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Version.txt` exists=False 
[D:]:                     GetSdkPath `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Version` exists=False 
[D:]:                     GetSdkPath `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Version.txt` exists=False 
[D:]:                     GetSdkPath `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Version` exists=False 
[D:]:                     GetSdkPath `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Version.txt` exists=False 
[D:]:                     GetSdkPath `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Version` exists=True 
[D:]:                     FindVersionFile: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Version, result=True
[I:]:                     Found Xamarin.Android 10.1.3.7
[I:]:                     Looking for Android SDK...
[D:]:                     ValidateAndroidSdkLocation: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk`, result=True
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 am broadcast -a "mono.android.intent.action.PACKAGE_VERSIONS" -e "packages" "Mono.Android.DebugRuntime,Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_28,com.companyname.listviewproblem" -n "Mono.Android.DebugRuntime/com.xamarin.mono.android.PackageVersions"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 cat /data/system/packages.xml
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 cat /dbdata/system/packages.xml
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 cat /data/system/packages.xml
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 cat /dbdata/system/packages.xml
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 "pm" "list" "packages" "-f"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 pm uninstall "Mono.Android.DebugRuntime"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 pm uninstall "Mono.Android.DebugRuntime"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 pm uninstall "Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_28"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 pm uninstall "Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_28"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 pm install -d "/data/local/tmp/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-debug.apk"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 rm "/data/local/tmp/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-debug.apk"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 pm install -d "/data/local/tmp/Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_28.apk"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 rm "/data/local/tmp/Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_28.apk"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 cat /data/system/packages.xml
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 cat /dbdata/system/packages.xml
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 "pm" "list" "packages" "-f"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 getprop
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 am broadcast -a "mono.android.intent.action.PACKAGE_VERSIONS" -e "packages" "Mono.Android.DebugRuntime,Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_28,com.companyname.listviewproblem" -n "Mono.Android.DebugRuntime/com.xamarin.mono.android.PackageVersions"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 cat /data/system/packages.xml
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 cat /dbdata/system/packages.xml
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 cat /data/system/packages.xml
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 cat /dbdata/system/packages.xml
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 "pm" "list" "packages" "-f"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 pm uninstall "Mono.Android.DebugRuntime"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 pm uninstall "Mono.Android.DebugRuntime"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 pm uninstall "Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_28"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 pm uninstall "Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_28"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 pm install -d "/data/local/tmp/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-debug.apk"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 rm "/data/local/tmp/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-debug.apk"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 pm install -d "/data/local/tmp/Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_28.apk"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 rm "/data/local/tmp/Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_28.apk"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 pm install -d "/data/local/tmp/com.companyname.listviewproblem-Signed.apk"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 rm "/data/local/tmp/com.companyname.listviewproblem-Signed.apk"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 "pm" "path" "com.companyname.listviewproblem"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 "echo" "-n" "${EMULATED_STORAGE_SOURCE}"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 "echo" "-n" "${EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET}"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 am broadcast -a "mono.android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_STORAGE_DIRECTORY" -n "Mono.Android.DebugRuntime/com.xamarin.mono.android.ExternalStorageDirectory"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 "echo" "-n" "${EXTERNAL_STORAGE}"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 cd /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__ || exit 1; for f in *; do echo $f; done;
[D:NotifyPhase]:          Enumerating remote files
[D:NotifyPhase]:          Determining required operations
[D:NotifyPhase]:          Creating directories
[D:NotifySync]:           CreateDirectory  /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__ 0
[D:NotifyPhase]:          Uploading files
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\ListViewProblem.Android.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/ListViewProblem.Android.dll 196608
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\FormsViewGroup.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/FormsViewGroup.dll 23152
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\ListViewProblem.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/ListViewProblem.dll 6656
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Android.Arch.Core.Common.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Arch.Core.Common.dll 37520
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Android.Arch.Core.Runtime.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Arch.Core.Runtime.dll 27280
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Common.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Common.dll 55960
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.LiveData.Core.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.LiveData.Core.dll 36520
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.LiveData.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.LiveData.dll 31392
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Runtime.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Runtime.dll 31392
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.ViewModel.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.ViewModel.dll 34976
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.dll 75952
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations.dll 160408
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Android.Support.AsyncLayoutInflater.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Support.AsyncLayoutInflater.dll 29352
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Android.Support.Collections.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Support.Collections.dll 98968
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat.dll 1849488
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Android.Support.CoordinaterLayout.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Support.CoordinaterLayout.dll 135840
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI.dll 47248
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils.dll 24216
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Android.Support.CursorAdapter.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Support.CursorAdapter.dll 65688
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs.dll 199320
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomView.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomView.dll 87192
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Support.Design.dll 1385616
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Android.Support.DocumentFile.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Support.DocumentFile.dll 35992
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Android.Support.DrawerLayout.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Support.DrawerLayout.dll 87192
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment.dll 389784
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Android.Support.Interpolator.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Support.Interpolator.dll 26784
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Android.Support.Loader.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Support.Loader.dll 91792
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Android.Support.LocalBroadcastManager.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Support.LocalBroadcastManager.dll 23728
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat.dll 798880
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Android.Support.Print.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Support.Print.dll 37008
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Android.Support.SlidingPaneLayout.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Support.SlidingPaneLayout.dll 65696
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Android.Support.SwipeRefreshLayout.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Support.SwipeRefreshLayout.dll 83624
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition.dll 313496
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.dll 41096
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat.dll 2103960
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView.dll 58520
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView.dll 882848
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable.dll 62112
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Android.Support.VersionedParcelable.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Support.VersionedParcelable.dll 116392
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Android.Support.ViewPager.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Android.Support.ViewPager.dll 131728
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Essentials.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Essentials.dll 169080
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll 1024632
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.dll 744960
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll 127104
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll 108664
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\ListViewProblem.Android.pdb /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/ListViewProblem.Android.pdb 33940
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\FormsViewGroup.pdb /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/FormsViewGroup.pdb 9332
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\ListViewProblem.pdb /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/ListViewProblem.pdb 1368
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Essentials.pdb /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Essentials.pdb 61216
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Forms.Core.pdb /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Forms.Core.pdb 391732
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.pdb /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.pdb 308856
[D:NotifySync]:           CopyFile C:\Projects\TinyGreenBits\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem\ListViewProblem.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.pdb /sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.pdb 39120
[D:NotifyPhase]:          Upload completed
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 date +%s
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 setprop "debug.mono.extra" "debug=127.0.0.1:29230:29231,timeout=1583182513,loglevel=0,server=y"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 getprop
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 "echo" "-n" "${EMULATED_STORAGE_SOURCE}"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 "echo" "-n" "${EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET}"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 am broadcast -a "mono.android.intent.action.EXTERNAL_STORAGE_DIRECTORY" -n "Mono.Android.DebugRuntime/com.xamarin.mono.android.ExternalStorageDirectory"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 "echo" "-n" "${EXTERNAL_STORAGE}"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 am start -a "android.intent.action.MAIN" -c "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" -n "com.companyname.listviewproblem/crc64ff42351e0d4fc5b3.MainActivity"
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 ps -A
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 am force-stop com.companyname.listviewproblem
[D:RunShellCommand]:      22X7N19322000015 setprop "debug.mono.connect" ""
```

Nothing really disturbing in here for as far as I can tell.

In the logcat I see something like this:

```
03-02 22:22:03.098: A/monodroid(29951): No assemblies found in '/data/user/0/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__' or '/storage/4A21-0000/Android/data/com.companyname.listviewproblem/files/.__override__'. Assuming this is part of Fast Deployment. Exiting...
03-02 22:22:03.102: E/libc++abi(29951): terminating
03-02 22:22:03.102: A/libc(29951): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 29951 (listviewproblem), pid 29951 (listviewproblem)
```

Switched to 'Release' mode an voila the application runs. Now the weird thing is that I've tried this 4 times and every time results in the same way, crash in Debug mode.

It looks like something 'general' is corrupted on my machine. What do I need to clean-up to get Debugging mode working again.

B.t.w. The Application I'm working on (this was just a project to prove a bug in Xamarin) works fine and I can run that in Debugging mode just fine.

Comment: You could try to start the Hyper-V manager, select the emulator you are trying to use, right-click, hit settings, click processor, click Compatibility, click checkbox “Migrate to a physical computer with a different processor version”.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Wendy. I'm not running on an emulator. I'm running on my Huawei P30 Pro Android Phone.

Comment: A moment ago ran it on the pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28_1 emulator without any problems.

Comment: Have you test on other device? Does it works well with the emulator or get the same error with Huawei P30 Pro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a setting in Visual Studio called 'Use Fast Deployment (debug mode only)'. If I turn that off debugging start working again on my phone.